# How param converters priority can be specified in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm Symfony 2 project going to define my own [param converter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) for my classes that inherit from `TenantableEntityInterface`. The framework itself provide a default a [`DoctrineConverter`](https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Request/ParamConverter/DoctrineParamConverter.php) while my own converter is quite similar but **should be the only one to be executed** (also for performance reasons).

How priority can be specified with param converters?

```
/**
 * @Service("request.doctrine_tenantable_entity_converter")
 * @Tag("request.param_converter")
 */
class DoctrineTenantableEntityConverter implements ParamConverterInterface
{
}
```

I've tried to pass a priority to the converter but it doesn't work:

```
/**
 * @Route("/show/{id}")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @ParamConverter("message", class="MyBundle:Message", priority=10)
 * @Template
 */
public function showAction(Message $message)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found it on an obscure page. Priority (-10 to 10) should be specified at **service definition** level (i'm using JMSDiExtraBundle).

An **higher priority** means that your own converter is executed before `DoctrineConverter`:

```
/**
 * @Service("request.doctrine_tenantable_entity_converter")
 * @Tag("request.param_converter", attributes = {"priority" = "10"})
 */
class DoctrineTenantableEntityConverter implements ParamConverterInterface {}
```

Comment: I'm extending DoctrineParamConverter yet even with a priority of 10 I can't seem to jam my ParamConverter in front of it, I've literally copied what you've provided, exited at the beginning of my apply method, and I still get "Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information." from the DoctrineParamConverter, like mine isn't even being registered (although errors I was getting before I got the syntax quite right would suggest it is). Any ideas?

Comment: @Steve I would suggest to ask a new question to solve the problem!

Comment: Turns out that forgetting to inject doctrine into constructor when extending DoctrineParamConverter will cause a silent fail, I assume it is because it make the paramconverter simply not match the controller action rather than cause a fatal of any kind, that's a few hours well spent..!